# How can I zip a Bamboo build log to store as an artifact for users to download?

Tags: bamboo

We have remote users in India and it takes a long time for them to view or download the logs after a build.  I would like to zip these and store as an artifact so they will be smaller therefore quicker to d/l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility to compress artifact and logs seems to be needed and was discussed many times  (i.e. [BAM-3512](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-3512), [BAM-2680](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-2680)), but it seems to be not implemented yet.

What will work for you is to:

- Save log as artifact ([find instruction here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/how-to-save-a-build-log-as-an-artifact-892498832.html), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206415/save-build-log-as-an-artifact-in-bamboo)) and share it.
- Add separate stage with job with following tasks:

  1. download logs artifact (from previous stage)
  2. compress logs
  3. save compressed logs as artifact

You can mark added stage as *Manual stage* (will be manually triggered on demand)